# Iterate over every row and compare a column value of a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe. I want to iterate over every row and compare the score column, if the value is >= value present in cut_off list.

```
                         seq  score    status
7    TTGTTCTCTGTGTATTTCAGGCT  10.42  positive
56                 CAGGTGAGA   9.22  positive
64   AATTCCTGTGGACTTTCAAGTAT   1.23  positive
116                AAGGTATAT   7.84  positive
145                AAGGTAATA   8.49  positive
172                TGGGTAGGT   6.86  positive
204                CAGGTAGAG   7.10  positive
214  GCGTTTCTTGAATCCAGCAGGGA   3.58  positive
269                GAGGTAATG   8.73  positive
274  CACCCATTCCTGTACCTTAGGTA   8.96  positive
325                GCCGTAAGG   5.46  positive
356                GAGGTGAGG   8.41  positive
```

```
cut_off = range(0, 11)
```

The code I tried so far is:

```
cutoff_list_pos = []
number_list_pos = []

cut_off = range(0, int(new_df['score'].max())+1)

for co in cut_off:
    for df in df_elements:
        val = (df['score']>=co).value_counts()
        cutoff_list_pos.append(co)
        number_list_pos.append(val)
```

The desired output is:

```
     cutoff  true  false
0          0            12.0            0
1          1            12.0            0
and so on..
```

If the score is >= to the value in cut_off, it should assign the row as true else false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parameter `keys` in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) by values of `cutoff_list_pos`, then transpose and convert index to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = (pd.concat(number_list_pos, axis=1, keys=cutoff_list_pos, sort=False)
       .T
       .rename_axis('cutoff')
       .reset_index())
```

Comment: Solved with another solution!! but this works well too

Answer (score 0):

Another pandas implementation:

```
res_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['cutoff', 'true'])
for i in range(1,int(df['score'].max()+1)):
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'cutoff': i, 'true': (df['score']>=i).sum()}, index=[i])
    res_df = pd.concat([res_df, temp_df])

res_df
    cutoff true
1       1   12
2       2   11
3       3   11
4       4   10
5       5   10
6       6    9
7       7    8
8       8    6
9       9    2
10     10    1
```